# Why github does not recognize my username in my commits?

Tags: github

I have two repositories on github, and my usernames on github and my local git name match. But for some reason github does not attribut my commits to me - so in statistics, there are no commits by the owner, only by some user with the same name. What could cause such behaviour?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Have you checked what e-mail address is associated with the commit message? I believe GitHub only attributes commits to you if the e-mail address associated with the commit is also connected to your GitHub account...

See [GitHub's cheat sheet](http://help.github.com/git-cheat-sheets/) for information about how to add e-mails to your  git config:

```
git config --global user.email "your_email@gmail.com"
```

If you type:

```
git config --list
```

you'll see all your current git configuration settings.

Comment: The problem is, there is no e-mail address associated with the commit.

Comment: If it's really important to you that those commits be attributed to you, I think the simplest solution would be to revert the commits, then recommit after having added your e-mail address to your git config...

Comment: And the address is also on your Github account?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.google.de/search?q=git+rewrite+commit+email (especially the first hit).

Comment: @Rogach if your e-mail address in the commit and your e-mail address on Github both match (and it's not that you just added the e-mail address afterwards --- in which case you should wait for Github to update), then you maybe you should e-mail help @ github. Making sure they match is all I've ever had to do...

Comment: Seems I had a typo in my github mail. Fixing it and making a push to github repo fixed it - all commits now belong to me :)

Comment: The link to the cheat sheet does not work anymore.

Answer (score 10):

You probably use a different email address for your commits, that you defined within the github settings.

On the one side you can define as many email addresses, that should be associated with you, as you like in your accounts settings under "Emails" on github.com.

On the other side you should set "your" email address in your git config

```
git config --global user.email "my@example.com"
```

The reason is, that git (it's not githubs fault ;)) uses email addresses as identifiers for commits. The name is only to display it, when requested.

Comment: git config user.email and mail in my id_rsa.pub key match.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons why my commits were not matching up to my user, is that although I was using the same email as in my user setting, the case of the email in the setting and the email in my terminal were not exactly the same. So for example, "EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM" is not the same as "example@example.com", although both will be allowed to push commits.