# How to push to GitHub repository with my GitHub username?

Tags: github

Apparently, my question is a duplicate of [Why github does not recognize my username in my commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419814/why-github-does-not-recognize-my-username-in-my-commits). I'm **wondering if I have to change these credential values every time I need to commit with a different account?**

I imported another GitHub Project as a new repository on GitHub. When I made some commits and push them to GitHub, I notice that the commits where not made by my GitHub account but appears as a name that isn't a user (not clickable to follow the user link).

I learnt that that was the name that I set earlier with the command `git config --global user.name "some name"`.

How can I change it so that when I commit, the commit will appear with my GitHub username on it?

I tried going to Windows Credential Manager and delete the `git:https://github.com` credential. When I tried committing after it did make me sign in to GitHub, but it still didn't commit with my username.

I'm using Visual Studio Code and committing via terminal.

Comment: Thank you @it'sjayway , I thought it would automatically set those value when i log in with my GitHub account. So, do I have to change these value manually every time when I need to commit with a different account?